# UIViewController stay active in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I use the following to open a new view controller

```
ViewController *mainMenu = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainview"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenu animated:NO];
```

When the mainview is active on the screen the application still runs old view controller (methods) in the background.

How i can stop the old view controller from running or make it inactive?

Comment: We need a lot more detail than this. What do you mean that it "still runs old view controller"? And nothing should run when the app's backgrounded.

Comment: I assume the Asker means that when View Controller A is in the background relative to View Controller B, both being view controllers of the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's ask ourselves this: what kind of methods run on a view controller?

I'm going to categorize the methods that are part of a `UIViewController` subclass into 4 categories (though there's clearly overlap among these categories).

1. **Life-cycle methods**.  These are methods such as `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, etc. that run as part of the view controller's life-cycle.  None of these methods should be running if the view is "in the background" other than, arguably, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:` which are technically called before the view has come to the foreground, and `viewDidDisappear:` which is technically called just after the view has left the foreground.  So we don't really need to worry about these.
2. **Delegate methods**.  Your view controller could delegate objects.  The delegate methods are called on your view controller whenever the object they're delegating calls them.  In the majority of the cases, we're talking about delegating some sort of UI element which is part of the view controller.  This UI element would be "in the background" any time the view controller is, so it shouldn't be calling delegate methods.
3. **NSTimer called methods**.  NSTimer can keep a strong reference to an object, and keep that object alive until the fire time ticks over and it calls the specified method on that object.  These methods are certainly likely to be called even if the view controller is in the background, but if you want to stop the timer from running if the view controller's view isn't visible, then just `invalidate` it in `viewDidDisappear:`.
4. **Miscellaneous methods**.  These methods don't necessarily into any of the above categories (though they could).  Most of the time these methods are called are from within the view controller themselves, so if nothing is being called from one of the first three categories, it will be rare that this category is called (unless the method is public).

So you've got methods running "in the background" on your view controller.  What category do they fall in?

If they're in the first category, then either you're calling a life-cycle method manually from somewhere (which I can't recommend against enough--there's no good reason to do this), or perhaps you don't understand the `UIViewController` life cycle.

If they're in the second category, then it's most likely good that they're being called.  If the Object A is being delegated by View Controller A and Object A is still working on some process and still requires delegation, then it's extraordinarily important that View Controller A is still responding to the delegation methods.  If you don't want this to happen, you need to stop Object A from requiring delegation.

If they're in the third category, invalidate your `NSTimer` objects when it's appropriate.  `NSTimer` doesn't just magically not do what you scheduled it to do.  You have to `invalidate` it in `viewDidDisappear` if you don't want it to call methods on the view controller when its view is not visible.

If they're in the fourth category, start by making sure you've not got public methods that you're calling manually from outside the view controller.  If you do, well stop calling them.  If you don't, go double check the first three categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the view controller that was active before is still executing code, I'd suggest doing the following to remove it from view and execution before pushing:

```
ViewController *mainMenu = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainview"];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO]; // Takes the old one away
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenu animated:NO];
```